# how to find which value has the maximum number of rows in a table using LinQ?

Tags: linq

Have a look at the below table:

```
student       Subject
badhon        English
jack          math
andy          physics
farhan        english
joe           english
foe           physics
```

Now I need to know which subject has the maximum entry & what the number is? I know its simple for experienced guys, but I'm really new to LinQ. So if you can give me any reference to study various LinQ Example, that would be too great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like you want to *group* by rows, then order them by count (descending) and take the first result:

```
var subjectsByCount = rows.GroupBy(row => row.Subject)
                          .Select(g => new { Subject = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
var biggestSubject = subjectsByCount.First();

// Now you can use biggestSubject.Subject and biggestSubject.Count
```

Strictly speaking, the ordering is unnecessary - with something like `MaxBy` in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) you could find the maximum without sorting the whole thing. But this is the simplest way if you just want to stay within vanilla LINQ.